# convert ms sql server to mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-server

how can I convert mssql mdf or bak file to mysql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Migrating from Microsoft SQL Server and Access to MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/migrating-from-microsoft.html)

Comment: See the Migration Tools section. One of them might work easily for you. However, you should read through the article so you'll be aware of any potential gotchas.